# ggplot2: add stat_function for particular domain?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add a curve to a plot I'm making with ggplot, but I only want the curve to appear for a particular domain.

I've tried various approaches using `stat_function`:

```
data <- data.frame(Date = ..., cases = ...)
end_date <- ... ## calculated from a date (e.g., Sys.Date()) minus an offset
start_date <- ... ## end_date - some offset
p1 <- ggplot(data) + aes(x=Date, y=cases) + ... ## data has Date, cases columns
p1 + stat_function(...something..., fun=function(t) ...)
```

where for something I've tried to put a new, subsetted chunk of data:

```
data = data[(start_date <= data$Date) & (data$Date <= end_date),] ## no change
```

and a new aes

```
aes = aes(xmin = start_date, xmax = end_date)
## error - thinks start_date / end_date don't exist,
## though they are declared earlier
```

Any suggestions?  I've also fiddled around with `annotate("path", ...)` but nothing concrete there.  I feel like this should be something easy, I just don't have my head around the "ggplot way" to make it happen.

It may also be relevant that I'm making these plots in a shiny application, though aside from funny crap w/ `data.table`, I haven't noticed that affecting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work, though it still feels very hacky to me:

```
data$fit <- ... # evaluate function on Date
relrows <- (start_date <= data$Date) & (data$Date <= end_date) 
p1 <- p1 + annotate("line", y=data$fit[relrows], x=data$Date[relrows])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another label as a new column in your dataframe.

```
df$newlabel[(start_date <= data$Date) $ (data$Date <= end_date)]<-a
```

then add groups to your `ggplot`

```
p1 <- ggplot(data) 
    + aes(x=Date, y=cases, group=newlabel, colour=newlabel)
    + geom_point()
    + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2), size=1)
```

Comment: I'll try this time permitting, but for now I'm going with ugly solution.  If I get to it and it works, I'll be back to up-vote.